# Sample Portion of 2 Different Images for CSS Background Color

Tags: html, css

We have a single Image URL which will return one of several external images which represent a deployment status (red, yellow, green, blue...).
[image: status passing]

The goal is to have a div with a green background if the resulting image is green, red for red etc. The strategy would be to "sample" the right-most portion of the image and then crop and stretch this across the background of the div.

Unfortunately, the different status images may be a different width depending on the status. So the word "passing", "cancelled", "failed" result in a slightly different length of image. For this reason, attempts with `background-size` have been unsuccessful since each image requires calculated offsets depending on the width.

The [following](https://jsfiddle.net/8dvkmnhz/) works in some cases but requires knowledge of the different widths of the images in order to calculate the offset (background-position)

```html
<div style="width:120px">
Status:
<span style="background-image: url(https://github.com/go-kit/kit/workflows/CI/badge.svg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: -96px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0); background-size: 100px, cover; float: right;">&nbsp;</span>
&nbsp;
<span style="background-image: url(https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b0fd8c978a9e20977dcfa2ab1f2ee17e7b00ba4f629c537828046c96183efa9d/68747470733a2f2f636f6465636f762e696f2f67682f676f2d6b69742f6b69742f6272616e63682f6d61737465722f67726170682f62616467652e737667); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: -114px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0); background-size: 120px, cover; float: right;">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

The problem here is we need to know the size of the image to calculate values for `background-size` and `background-position` or the image. If we set a fixed size we get the wrong sample position [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8dvkmnhz/1/) and see some text:

[image]

Is there a better way to sample a section of the image (say X=width-5px, Y=5px) and then stretch this sample pixel across an entire div without knowing the width in advance?

Comment: Ideally, this would not rely on those images to begin with - but query the deployment status from some API, that gives a result in text form, so that you can easily determine what the status actually _is_, and then set an appropriate color for your display element based on that. Where are you getting those images from, and have you checked if there isn't a proper way to get the _information_ you need?

Comment: This approach eliminates the need for any code. It may be quick and dirty but that is sufficient here.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a good job for `border-image`:

```css
.e {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  border-image: var(--img) 48% 1 48% 0/0 100% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="e" style="--img:url(https://github.com/go-kit/kit/workflows/CI/badge.svg)"></div>
<div class="e" style="--img:url(https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b0fd8c978a9e20977dcfa2ab1f2ee17e7b00ba4f629c537828046c96183efa9d/68747470733a2f2f636f6465636f762e696f2f67682f676f2d6b69742f6b69742f6272616e63682f6d61737465722f67726170682f62616467652e737667)"></div>
<div class="e" style="--img:url(https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b0fd8c978a9e20977dcfa2ab1f2ee17e7b00ba4f629c537828046c96183efa9d/68747470733a2f2f636f6465636f762e696f2f67682f676f2d6b69742f6b69742f6272616e63682f6d61737465722f67726170682f62616467652e737667)"></div>
```

I know the code is not easy to understand (I am preparing a big article for such tricks) but the idea is to slice one pixel width from the right center of the image and stretch it to the whole element

Comment: this just appears as 3 empty rectangles in google chrome. In FF it works OK

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I am using chrome to test ...

Comment: The 3 empty rectangles are correct, they are however the correct color and thus an acceptable solution.

Comment: they all appear as black borders which is weird

Comment: Would be nice if you could explain the numbers and how they hopefully don't relate to different image sizes...

Comment: The black border is easily removed by dropping the with `outline: 1px solid;` directive.

Comment: @Marc you will need to wait until I publish my article (https://css-articles.com/) where I will have a detailed explanation of border-image but if the last 1px column of your image doesn't contain any text then you won't have any issue whatever the image is

Comment: I understand how to remove the border but what I get is [simple, empty rectangles](https://imgur.com/a/6XB6zY8) with no colours

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius change the 49% with a smaller value (47% for example). You are probably face rounding issue that will give the computed value the same as 50% which will give an empty result

Comment: If I set `border:1px solid black;` all is well - without that border I see empty rectangles... odd

Comment: Looks fine w/o border to me: https://jsfiddle.net/ybL5fen1/